# EditText requestFocus()?

Tags: android

I got a problem with requestFocus.

First, this is my source code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etGLNum2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btGLCalculate"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/gl_num2_hint"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etGLNum1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/etGLNum2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btGLCalculate"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/gl_num1_hint"
    android:inputType="number">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGLResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etGLNum2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/result"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btGLCalculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvGLResult"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etGLNum1"
    android:text="@string/calculate" />
```

As you see, focus have to go to etGLNum1, but it always goes to etGLNum2.

I already tried adding `etGLNum1.requestFocus();` from my java file but it didn't worked.

What should i do?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Add  `requestFocus` in your `Edittext`.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etGLNum2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btGLCalculate"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/gl_num2_hint"
    android:inputType="number">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 try this :-
 etGLNum2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View rv, boolean hasFocus) {

                       etGLNum2.clearFocus();
                   etGLNum1.requestFocus();



         }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add xml all editexts:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/gl_num2_hint"
    android:inputType="number" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` write:

```
EditText etGLNum1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etGLNum1);
etGLNum1.requestFocus();
etGLNum1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
    {
        //enter code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With what i have experienced is, Android have a a default behavior of giving focus to the first focusable element found in the current surface(if we have not set any default element to focusable).
You can use `etGLNum1.setFocusable(true)` (before setContentView() call) then `etGLNum1.requestFocus()` (after setContentView() call) from your onCreate()..
It should work..